# Search a List of string array to find a value in matching element and return another element in same array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

So I have

```
    List<string[]> listy = new List<string[]>();

    listy.add('a','1','blue');
    listy.add('b','2','yellow');
```

And i want to search through all of the list ti find the index where the array containing 'yellow' is, and return the first element value, in this case 'b'.

Is there a way to do this with built in functions or am i going to need to write my own search here?

Relatively new to c# and not aware of good practice or all the built in functions. Lists and arrays im ok with but lists of arrays baffles me somewhat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wow guys you're all amazing thankyou. I think i need to read around linq and get my head around it. cant wait to try some of these out tomorrow! thanks in advance to all of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already suggested, the easiest way to do this involves a very powerful C# feature called [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) ("Language INtegrated Queries). It gives you a SQL-like syntax for querying collections of objects (or databases, or XML documents, or JSON documents).

To make LINQ work, you will need to add this at the top of your source code file:

`using System.Linq;`

Then you can write:

```
IEnumerable<string> yellowThings = 
    from stringArray in listy
    where stringArray.Contains("yellow")
    select stringArray[0];
```

Or equivalently:

```
IEnumerable<string> yellowThings =
    listy.Where(strings => strings.Contains("yellow"))
         .Select(strings => strings[0]);
```

At this point, `yellowThings` is an object containing *a description of the query that you want to run.* You can write other LINQ queries on top of it if you want, and it won't actually perform the search until you ask to see the results.

You now have several options...

Loop over the yellow things:

```
foreach(string thing in yellowThings)
{
    // do something with thing...
}
```

(Don't do this more than once, otherwise the query will be evaluated repeatedly.)

Get a list or array :

```
List<string> listOfYellowThings = yellowThings.ToList();
string[] arrayOfYellowThings = yellowThings.ToArray();
```

If you expect to have *exactly one* yellow thing:

```
string result = yellowThings.Single();
// Will throw an exception if the number of matches is zero or greater than 1
```

If you expect to have *either zero or one* yellow things:

```
string result = yellowThings.SingleOrDefault();
// result will be null if there are no matches.
// An exception will be thrown if there is more than one match.
```

If you expect to have *one or more* yellow things, but only want the first one:

```
string result = yellowThings.First();
// Will throw an exception if there are no yellow things
```

If you expect to have *zero or more* yellow things, but only want the first one if it exists:

```
string result = yellowThings.FirstOrDefault();
// result will be null if there are no yellow things.
```

Comment: You, Sir, are fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the problem explanation provided by you following is the solution I can suggest.

```
List<string[]> listy = new List<string[]>();

listy.Add(new string[] { "a", "1", "blue"});
listy.Add(new string[] { "b", "2", "yellow"});

var target = listy.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Contains("yellow"));

if (target != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(target[0]);
}
```

This should solve your issue. Let me know if I am missing any use case here.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider changing the data structure,

Have a class for your data as follows,

```
public class Myclas
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string color { get; set; }
        }
```

And then,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<Myclas> listy = new List<Myclas>();
   listy.Add(new Myclas { name = "a", id = 1, color = "blue" });
   listy.Add(new Myclas { name = "b", id = 1, color = "yellow" });
   var result = listy.FirstOrDefault(t => t.color == "yellow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current situation is

```
List<string[]> listy = new List<string[]>();

listy.Add(new string[]{"a","1","blue"});
listy.Add(new string[]{"b","2","yellow"});
```

Now there are Linq methods, so this is what you're trying to do

```
var result = listy.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("yellow"))?[0];
```